# Visual Studio App Center with UWP on Release

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

I have a problem with https://appcenter.ms/apps
I have a UWP application, on my computer with visual studio 2017 whether it is in release or in debug any operation perfectly work, the application starts.

I created a build on Visual Studio Team Services with a deployment directly into a group in App Center. Both stages are going very well.

If I run the debug build and download the app from the App Center application, the application launches.

On the other hand if I launch the build in release, I download with the same way the application but as soon as it starts it crash. I tried to put a log system in place but I think the application crash from the beginning.

I do not understand why it works perfectly in debug and not in release with only difference the choice of build debug or release.
I'm desperate to understand where this comes from.

Comment: The difference between the debug and release build is the [.NET Native](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/). In release mode, it will enable the .net native to build your app package. I would suggest that you need to check your app log and check if there're some exception when your app launches.

Comment: I think it can come from that. But this should be a problem for me on my computer while in release on my computer it works very well.
But as soon as I publish on app center after the build of VSTS, the application crashes directly after the launch.
I probably have an exception but today I do not see which, can be an injection of dependencies but I do not see why it would work more on my computer.

Comment: You are not alone. I have the same problem for weeks now. Did you solve it?